# Is there a command to batch change time zones of files?

Tags: bash, datetime, photo, exif

I recently went to Japan (UTC+9) from the UK, however, when I returned I forgot to change the time zone on my DLSR camera back to GMT. Since the files are now on my Linux machine, is there a way to batch change the time stamps for the pictures I have taken since I came home, so that they're on GMT rather than 9 hours ahead?

Comment: @Kent Please do not use the comments section to answer questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found this, using exiftool:

```
exiftool "-AllDates+=1:12:28 14:54:32" -verbose *.jpg
```

> to adjust all JPG image dates by adding 1 year, 12 month, 28 days, 14 hours, 54 minutes, 32 seconds

At [photo.stackexchange: How to shift EXIF date/time created by time in days, hours, minutes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/how-to-shift-exif-date-time-created-by-time-in-days-hours-minutes)

So for shifting down all your photos by 9 hours, you could:

```
exiftool "-AllDates-=09:00:00" /path/to/IMG*.JPG
```

Then

```
exiftool '-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal' /path/to/IMG*.JPG
```

For setting file system date/time from exif infos.

Comment: N.B. to other readers: [there isn't really any timezone setting in EXIF](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/97149/3576) (at least not a widely supported one) so it is indeed the case that you have to shuffle the actual timestamp. In other scenarios, this would be the wrong solution.